# Does the function have derivatives at $x=0$

Tags: derivatives

[derivatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxZEj.gif)

Hey, in this question I succeeded the first part.

**Part B:**

I fail to show that either have no derivative at the point $x = 0$.
I try on the definition of derivative and lodged.

**Part C:**

I believe I can understand with part B.

thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!
See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You were asked whether or not $f(x)$ has a derivative at $x=0$, and if so, compute.
$f(x)$ at $x=0$ is $0$ as stated by the problem, and it **does** in fact have a derivative. The derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is $0$, which is a **constant**.

The derivative of any **constant** is $0$.
Therefore, the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ is $0$.